# ConfigurationManager connection string is null in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration, user-controls

I have an application which gets data to the forms through a datalayer which uses something like this:

```
public DataTable get(String query, ArrayList parameters = null)
{            
   using (iDB2Connection cn =  new iDB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iseries"].ToString()))
   {
       // get the data and return them    
   }
}
```

I have forms which get data and this works fine.

However, I created a UserControl which gets data through this method which works fine when I run my project, however, the form which contains the UserControl throws a designer exception.

> "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved: "

I found that the error is located at the retrieval of the connection string from the `<appSettings>`.

It throws a nullpointerexception.

But only in design mode. When I ignore it, everything works fine, however, I would like to know how to resolve this.

Why are my `<appSettings>` null when accessing them through my UserControl?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems my UserControl doesn't recognize the `<appSettings>` at all.

When I put this code in my UserControl Load event I get a nullreference as well.

```
private void SelectUser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   txtLocation.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["location"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, Winforms, or what?

Comment: It's winforms, I added the tag.

Comment: Are you able to *Read* connection string value from any other place ?

Comment: Yes, everything works fine except for reading the values from a UserControl. In a "normal" form, I can read it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, in designmode the usercontrol already executes the code in the Load-event.
Because the App.config isn't available in designmode it isn't found and therefore not loaded.
So I made a little check around it to check if in designmode or not:

```
bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
if (designMode)
{
    string location = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["location"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below article depicts this issue in WPF/Win Forms. Please have a look...

[MS Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d45e2126-4d38-40f8-ba5d-f578adcb8b7d/configurationmanagers-connectionstrings-null-in-user-control-project?forum=wpf)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to tweak how you're fetching your `ConnectionString`.

```
using (iDB2Connection cn =  new iDB2Connection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iseries"].ConnectionString)
{
    //get the data and return them    
}
```

Comment: Nope, still getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." ConfigurationManager settings are null in a usercontrol for some reason.