# Connection String is NULL on design time

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, connection-string, oledb

I have user control that use on connection string from `App.config`:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="......." providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

at run time everything worked! But at design time I get the following error about the connection string :

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<connection_name>"]` is null.

There is a way to get the connection string on design time?

Comment: I believe you'll need to load `ConfigurationManager` manually from file (web.config) in a "`if` code is running in design mode"

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer. You can post an answer how to do this?

Comment: I'm at work now, but I believe it's a good hint... try it yourself

Comment: Your issue seems very similar to the issue described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785529/configurationmanager-connection-string-is-null-in-usercontrol. Does it help?